# Is every set relation $R$ that is extensional and well-founded, necessarily linear?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $R$ be the relation. Due to extensionality and well-foundedness, exists a unique minimal element and a unique successor, And the one after that, and a unique limit point for them. Does this necessarily mean that the relation is a well-ordering? I cannot find any counterexample.

Comment: What do you mean by $R$ is extensional?

Comment: If $\{x|x<x_1 \}=\{x|x<x_2 \}$ then $x_1 =x_2$.

Comment: What's the definition of well-founded you're using? Because I'm familiar with [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-founded_relation), which does *not* give you that minimal elements are unique, or that you have a unique successor operation.

Answer (score 3):

A relation that is extensional and well-founded is not necessarily a well-order.

For instance take relation $\in_A$ on transitive set: $$A=\{0,1,2,\{1,2\}\}$$ where $0:=\varnothing$, $1:=\{0\}$ and $2:=\{0,1\}$.

The elements $0$ and $\{1,2\}$ are incomparable.

---

A relation that is extensional and well-founded will be a well-order iff the relation is also transitive.

Further you might be interested in the [Mostowski collapse lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mostowski_collapse_lemma).